# What's the meaning if this Composer error?

Tags: composer-php

I'm using Composer for a while and for many projects now, but I don't like the error handling of it.

I've a local composer repository and have a package that I want to include from it.

```
client-app (dev) --> require my-core 2.2.*
my-core (2.2.1) --> requires laravel4 4.1.24
```

But I get the following error when I try to install:

```
E:\Development\project>composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for my-repo/client-app dev-default -> satisfiable by my-repo/client-app[dev-default].
    - my-repo/client-app dev-default requires my-repo/my-core 2.2.* -> satisfiable by my-repo/my-core[v2.2, v2.2.1].
    - my-repo/my-core v2.2 requires laravel/framework 4.1.24 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.1.24].
    - my-repo/my-core v2.2.1 requires laravel/framework 4.1.24 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.1.24].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.24
```

How do you read this output? Because I read it like:

- client-app is requested to install ... We found a package that matches!
- client-app needs the package my-core ... We found two matches that can be installed!
- The first option needs L4 4.1.24 ... Hey we found that one!
- The second option needs L4 4.1.24 ... Hey we found that one too!
- So... don't install laravel 4..

My question is then, what's the problem?

Comment: Do you start from scratch (i.e. no installed vendor folder, and no existing composer.lock file), or do you have these files preexisting? Can it be that you already have a version of Laravel installed, but it isn't 4.1.24?

Comment: @Sven I deleted the `composer.lock` file and the `vendor` folder before running the `composer install` command.

Comment: You should consider removing the fixed Laravel version requirement in the my-core components. Make it `4.1.*` rather than fixed at the specific `4.1.24`. That may help Composer to work things out, and will also ensure that you get the latest patch release of the 4.1 branch (I think the last patch was 4.1.31?). It's also worth noting that Laravel 4.1 is now obsolete - it isn't being developed any more. The current version is 5.1, which has a lot of new features that you'd probably want to be using.